# Load a dynamic component on Angular 2 RC6 but without defining entityComponents on parent Component

Tags: angular

I built a Plugin architecture where user can load their on plugins so I cannot harcode in the code the entityComponents on the container because as the user will load it, I don't know which component the user will load. Apart from that, the user could code their on plugins.

The funny thing is that the solution is in a book called Mastering Angular 2 Components but it was wrote based on RC1

Have anyone found the solution???

Comment: have you found any solution? I also need to implement this scenario!